# Upgrading projects to work in session-independent mode

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

As we know, when I deploy a WAR file that has been built using WL 6.2 to MFP7.1, the server migrate the WAR file from 6.2 to 7.1 automatically using its own worklight-jee-library.jar file, making the runtime to function as WAR 7.1 (Please correct me if I’m wrong). However, based on the note mentioned in the URL:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.upgrade.doc/devenv/t_upgrading_projects_session_depend.html

Note: Clients that were created using a version of IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation earlier than V7.1.0 do not work with a MobileFirst Server that is operating in the new session-independent mode. So, to serve users who are using the session-independent mode, as well as existing users who are using session-dependent mode, you must deploy the new V7.1.0 WAR with its V7.1.0 artifacts, but WITHOUT removing the old WAR.

**What does it mean "WITHOUT removing the old WAR.”?** There won’t be old WAR as the WAR version now is V7.1! which has been communicated to us that we can't deploy old WAR without doing the migration.

During the WAR deployment, we get this:

```
[configureapplicationserver] INFO: FWLST2017I: The project WAR file was successfully migrated from version 6.2.0.01.20150329-1923 to version 7.1.0.00.20160401-2103. The migrated project WAR file is located in '/tmp/wla5601747575/MobileBanking.war'.
[configureapplicationserver] ** Created migrated war file
```

**What is the WAR deployed now? is it version 7.1 or still 6.2?**

Edit:

1. Project is built and complied using WL 6.2
2. artifacts created are WAR - WLAPP and adapters using WL 6.2 ant tasks.
3. Need to deploy all those artifacts to MFP 7.1 as it is. No
   Migration done to those artifacts as to serve my live clients.
4. I'm taking all those artifacts to MFP server and start the deployment.
5. The WAR file is being migrated to 7.1 during the deployment (Deployment is done using MFP Ant task).
6. After the runtime is created. I'm deploying the 6.2 WLAPP and 6.2 Adapters inside the runtime.

When MFP server deploy the WAR file which is built from 6.2, what is the WAR version after the deployment?

If the WAR is still 6.2, why do I see "mfp.session.independent" property inside my runtime?

If the server is migrating the WAR by itself and making it 7.1, then how can I deploy an old WAR to MFP7.1 without any modification on it?

Answer (score 0):

When building your project with the v7.1 Studio or the 7.1 Ant tasks, this will create the 7.1 war file.

You can still deploy your old war from 6.2 along side your 7.1 war file. It implies you're supposed to back it up.

Comment: My Project is built using 6.2 studio and 6.2 ant task, my war version is 6.2. I'm placing the war in my MFP directory to deploy where the migration is happening. What is the war version that is deployed to MFP based on my case? Is it still 6.2 or changed to be 7.1?

Comment: You didn't do any migration in what you're writing. You just put an existing war file in some folder. You need to migrate **your project**. That's the action that creates a valid 7.1 war file.

Comment: Plus, I wouldn't run a session-dependent project next to a session-independent project... it's more than just running the project. You need to account to the way adapters behave in session-independent mode as well as to the way the server works (no sessions, no global vars in adapters and so on). I suggest that you will read the IBM Knowledge Center topics before you do anything.

Comment: I can't migrate my project as I need to serve my live clients who are still using 6.2. I can't put two live servers one for 6.2 and other for 7.1 (My problem would be solved if I have this option). I need to place my 6.2 artifices on MFP as is. (WAR- WLAPP and adapters). my question is about the war. What is the WAR version after the deployment is completed?

Comment: An application server that hosts MobileFirst Server 7.1 can still serve applications that belong to 6.2 and 7.1 (2 different war files, both deployed to the same server - it's a supported topology). I still don't understand what you're talking about. Unless you took your PROJECT and executed a BUILD PROCESS on it, using the 7.1 ANT OR STUDIO, it not a migrated war. It's still the SAME WAR as it was before.

Comment: If it is the SAME WAR as it was before, why do I see this "mfp.session.independent" property in my runtime.? If I'm taking the exact same WAR file built from 6.2 and deploy it to the MFP. Why MFP is adding properties that weren't existed in the original WAR. Can you explain this?

Comment: No, I can't explain because something is missing in your explanation. You don't just take a war and put it elsewhere and it magically gets migrated. I don't understand what you're *really* are doing there. Edit your question with a list of steps. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113343/discussion-between-hussam-eddin-and-idan-adar).

Comment: Edited my question

Comment: You are using the 6.2 ant to deploy to the 7.1 server? Doesn't sound like it. You can't use 6.2 ant to deploy to 7.1. This tells me you're likely using 7.1 ant and that means it got migrated to 7.1.

Comment: Then you're migrating your war. You're not supposed to migrate it if you don't want to migrate. You're supposed to simply manually place the war in the folder in your application server and configure the server.xml with it. Nothing else.

Comment: Please provide the steps on how this will be done manually or any doc. I was planning to do this test where I will change this property to "FALSE" inside my 7.1 Ant file which is responsible to deploy the runtime "<property name="config.migration.tool.enable" value="true"></property>"

Comment: My Test failed. it still migrating even after I set the value to "false".

Comment: I opened a PMR to keep an official tracking of the issue: Service Request 11540 047 649